# Understanding getElementById, etc

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm learning Javascript, and I just want to fully understand where these methods come from:

- document.getElementByID
- document.querySelector
  .
  .
  .
- etc

I understand what they do, and how to use them. I know that "document" is the main object and you can either use the "dot" notation or "['']" to access values using the keys of the object. But I can't seem to find getElementID under the Document object when I type in the Chrome's console: console.dir(document)

In Python, we have special methods that come with Python, are these 'special' methods? So they do need to be part of the Document object specifically?

I know this might be a silly question, but I just want to fully understand where everything comes from. Thank you guys, I appreciate the help.

Regards,

Anthony

Comment: If you want to inspect the Document object that way in devtools, you need to instead do this: `console.dir(Document.prototype)`.

And in general to see the difference between `document` and `Document`: `console.dir(document)` vs `console.dir(Document)`

…Or something that maybe helps to more clearly see the difference: `console.dir(document.constructor)` vs `console.dir(Document.constructor)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `document` object is a child of the `window` object. These are considered "browser built-in globals" in JavaScript.

Child properties of the window object can be accessed directly like `console.log(document)` but can also be used with `console.log(window.document)` which is the same thing.

The methods such as `getElementById` etc exist under the `documents`'s prototype. You can view this by using `console.dir(Document.prototype)`.

You can read more about prototypes here — https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

Hopefully that answers your question!

Answer (score 2):

These methods exist inside `__proto__`, they are apart of the [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) of the `document` object.

Answer (score 1):

A good analogy to use is the standard library of Python. (Note that i'm not familiar with Python, so if I get anything wrong, feel free to correct me).

A Python installation comes with a standard library - a collection of objects, along with their corresponding methods, that are bundled into the Python runtime.

In a similar way, Javascript, when running in the browser environment, also has a 'standard library' - the Document Object Model or DOM. This is a collection of objects, along with their corresponding methods, that are bundled into the JavaScript runtime. Some of these objects include `window`, `location` and `document`. And, each of these bundled objects has several methods attached to them. So, in your example, the bundled `document` object has several methods, including your `getElementById` etc.

The fact that they are not visible when you do `console.dir` doesn't mean they don't exist on the `document` object. `console.dir` may simply be excluding them from its output (why? I can't say).

But if you `console.log` the various properties of the `document` object, you'll see that they are all there.